# Giving SelectedIndex -1 in Listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox

I'm having listbox and getting selected item. The code is

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            string str =""; 
            if (index == 0)
            {
                 str = (string)Text1.Text;
            }
            else if (index == 1)
            {
                 str = (string)Text2.Text;
            }
            else if (index == 2)
            {
                 str = (string)Text3.Text;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(str);
          //  listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;            
        }
```

By this above code, after I selected one item,blue color bar is displaying in selected item, to avoid that I gave `listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;`.
If I gave this this function is get executed twice.and the message box shows empty string.
Why is it happening? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try construction like this:

```
listBox1.SelectionChanged -= listBox1_SelectionChanged;
listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
listBox1.SelectionChanged += listBox1_SelectionChanged;
```

listBox1.SelectedIndex is calling SelectionChanged event so this function is called twice.